# Bash Tokenization Errors on Jenkins JNLP Slave

Tags: jenkins, shell-script, bash

Why might the below bash commands give me an error on a Jenkins JNLP slave in Kubernetes cluster? Each work on a local machine.

---

**Error:** `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

```
IFS='/' read -r -a branch <<< "${1}"
```

---

**Error:** `Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")`:

```
IFS='/'
branch=($1)
```

---

## Environment Details

- JNLP Slave is using Dockerhub [jenkins/jnlp-slave:latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jnlp-slave/dockerfile)
- Slave being ran with [kubernetes plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin)
- Jenkins v2.156 on master.
- Command is from a sourced function in another script. (e.g. `. "/script.bash"`)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say this is a the best answer so I do hope someone can provide a better clarification.

It seems the default shell for `sh()` in Jenkins is Bourne.  By updating the `sh()` with the correct shell this allows the below usage:

```
sh'''#!/bin/bash
    IFS='/'
    branch=($1)
    # Use it.
'''
```

This doesn't resolve the the redirection error.  Also I would think by updating the default shell in the image with `chsh -s /bin/bash` I wouldn't need to set it but I still do.